# Scalamock: How to get "expects" for Proxy mocks?

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalamock

I am using Scalamock with ScalaTest, and am trying to mock a Java interface. I currently have:

```
private val _iface = mock [MyInterface]
```

now I want to do

```
_iface expects `someMethod returning "foo" once
```

But the compiler does not find `expects`.

I imported `org.scalatest._` and `org.scalamock.scalatest._`. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, proxy mocks are not supported very well in ScalaMock 3, and I think they will be completely removed in ScalaMock 4. Do you really need to use proxy mocks instead macro mocks?

This should work:

```
package example

import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.Matchers
import org.scalamock.scalatest.proxy.MockFactory

trait MyInterface {
    def someMethod : String
}

class MyTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
  "MyInterface" should "work" in {
    val m = mock[MyInterface]
    m.expects('someMethod)().returning("foo")
    m.someMethod shouldBe "foo"
  }
}
```

If not, please check [ScalaMock proxy mocks unit tests](https://github.com/pawel-wiejacha/ScalaMock/blob/master/core_tests/src/test/scala/com/paulbutcher/test/proxy/ProxyMockTest.scala) for more examples.

Comment: This example does not even find `mock`. I now stick with Mockito when needing such functionality.

Comment: @rabejens it did not find the `mock` because `MyInterface` was not defined in my example. I've updated the example - it compiles and works with ScalaMock 3.2.x. Please note I'm mixing ScalaTest suite with `org.scalamock.scalatest.proxy.MockFactory`

Comment: I try to mock a Java interface with this technique, and even when I import this and do `mock[MyInterface]`, it does not find `mock`.

Comment: @rabejens please double check your test. I removed the `MyInterface` trait, created `src/main/java/example/MyInterface.java`, moved my test to `src/test/scala/example/MyTest.scala` and it works. I'm using scala-2.11.1 and ScalaMock-3.2.2.

Comment: I double checked it. I even copy-pasted your code and it does not find `mock` there either. Maybe it is because I am building with Maven and miss some dependencies. Which dependencies did you specify for this to work? I currently have `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11`, `org.scalamock:scalamock-core_2.11` and `org.scalamock:scalamock-scalatest-support_2.11`.

Comment: `org.scalamock:scalamock-scalatest-support_2.11` should be enough.

@rabejens I've just created a gist for you: https://gist.github.com/99b61345630a0beacd4d.git - it consists only of 3 files. You can clone it, move two files to correct folders (unfortunately, gists cannot have subfolders), and run `sbt test`. It will work. Then you experiment with minimal `pom.xml` to make this example work under maven.

Comment: Your link just returns an empty page.

Comment: use `git clone <url>` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something more like:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory

class MyTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MockFactory {
  "MyInterface" should "work" in {
    val m = mock[MyInterface]
    (m.someMethod _).expects().returning("foo")
    m.someMethod shouldBe "foo"
  }
}
```

I think the expects arg is expecting the arg to the function

Answer (score 1):

I use `scalaMock` version `4.1.0`, this works for me:

For some trait:

```
trait MyInterface { def someMethod(n1: Int, n2: Int) }
```

This should be put into a test

```
val myInterfaceMock = mock[MyInterface]

myInterfaceMock.someMethod _ expects (1,2)
```

For more reading: [scalaMock Guide](http://scalamock.org/user-guide/features/), you'll find some examples there